# ImportError: No module named PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

Хотел установить pyqt4 под python 2й версии.Скачал zip файл с официального сайта распаковал.Импортировал модуль в программе а компилятор выдаёт ошибку которая в заголовке вопроса.

Comment: Директория в которую распаковали архив есть в sys.path?

Comment: С официального сайта можно скачать только исходный код, который придётся ещё скопилировать и установить. Почему не воспользуетесь пакетным менеджером?